# HUAWEI router not passing a Xirrus AP a good download speed?

Tags: networking, wifi

Right so I have a fun one for you lot.

```
192.168.8.1 HUAWEI Router B315 DHCP Range (.100-.200) DNS 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 

192.168.8.110 Xirrus AP XR500 DNS 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

So what I'm trying to do or rather having trouble with.

LAN PORT 2 (on the Huawei Router is connected to the Xirrus AP). I can access the AP once connected via LAN or Via WIFI

Here is the issue:

- Connected to the Router directly LAN 19.2mb/s download
- Connected to the Router directly WIFI 16.3mb/s download
- Created SSID on AP - Band Both, QoS 0, Roaming L2  (everything else is unchecked or on open)
- Connect to my new SSID
- Download 0.03mb/s <-- how is this happening

Clarification on the question: I want to know why the speed is dropping rather then just not working at all.

Note: Upload remains the same in all scenarios!

NOTE: can't tag XIRRUS or HUAWEI due to rep points.

Comment: This was probably downvoted as it likely belongs on _Server Fault_ - it is an infrastructure/server question rather than a programming one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my little question was a fault in the Cat 6 connecting the AP power module to the HUAWEI Router. If any one has this set-up and want to ask more mail me, to any that want to know what this is for (general dislike for dodgy setups) it's a demo system for displaying infrastructure projects to external clients.